chi squared distribution from multivariate normal distribution
Assume $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has multivariate normal distribution with zero mean and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, which has rank less than $n$. Assume $G$ is generalised inverse of $\Sigma$. What is the distribution $X^{T} G X$? Is it chi-squared with $rank(X)$ degrees of freedom?

Why is $G$ introduced but not used anywhere else in your question? Did you mean to write $X^TGX$ instead of $X^T\Sigma X$?

Dear Dilip Sarwate, I edited.

We have $X\sim \mathcal N_n(0, \Sigma)$. Denote $r=\mathrm{rank}(\Sigma)$. Let $G$ be a generalized inverse (g-inverse) of the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, i.e. it holds that $\Sigma G \Sigma = \Sigma$.
Then, according to the definition of the multivariate normal distribution, we have $X=C\cdot Z$ with $Z\sim \mathcal N_r(0,\Bbb I_r)$, $C\in\Bbb R^{n\times r}$ with $\mathrm{rank}(C)=r$ and $\Sigma=CC'$ ($C'$ denoting the transpose of $C$).
$$ \implies X'GX = Z'C'GCZ = Z'BZ
$$
with $B:=C'GC\in\Bbb R^{r\times r}$.
We have to show that $Z'BZ \sim \chi^2_r$. To achieve this, we prove two claims first.

The matrix $B$ is idempotent, i.e. $B^2=B$.
$B$ is normal, i.e. $BB' = B'B$.

Ad 1.:
Since $G$ is a g-inverse of $\Sigma=CC'$, we have
$$ \Sigma G \Sigma G \Sigma = \Sigma G\Sigma \\
\implies CC'GCC'GCC' = CC'GCC' \\
\implies C'CC'GCC'GCC'C = C'CC'GCC'C
$$
where we have multiplied with $C'$ from the left and $C$ from the right in order to get the last equation. Now observe that $\mathrm{rank}(C'C)=r$ so that the inverse $(C'C)^{-1}$ exists. After multiplying from the left and the right with this inverse, we get
$$ C'GCC'GC = C'GC \\
\implies B^2 = B
$$
Ad 2.: We have
$$
BB' = C'GCC'G'C \\
\implies C'CBB' = C'CC'GCC'G'C = C'\Sigma G\Sigma G'C = C'\Sigma G'C \\
\implies C'CBB'C'C = C'\Sigma G'CC'C = C'\Sigma G' \Sigma C = C'\Sigma C
$$
The last step uses the fact that $G'$ is also a g-inverse of $\Sigma$ since the latter is symmetric. This equality can be established along the same lines for $B'B$, i.e.
$$
C'CB'BC'C = C'\Sigma C
$$
Using the same argument as above w.r.t. $C'C$ completes the proof of 2.
Since $B$ is normal (2.), a spectral decomposition exists with an orthogonal matrix $P\in\Bbb R^{r\times r}$, $P^{-1}=P'$, $\Delta = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_r)$, in the form $B = P\Delta P'$, or $\Delta = P'BP$. See Theorem 2.5.3 in [1].
We set $Y:=P'Z$, then $Y\sim\mathcal N(0, \Bbb I_r)$ since $\mathrm{Cov}(Y)=\Bbb E[YY'] = \Bbb E[P'ZZ'P]= P'\Bbb E[ZZ']P = P'P = \Bbb I_r$.
Furthermore, since $Z=PY$ due to $(P')^{-1}=P$, it holds that
$$
Z'BZ = (PY)'B(PY) = Y'P'BPY = Y'P'P\Delta P'PY = Y'\Delta Y \\
= \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i Y^2_i, \ \mathrm{ where}\ \ Y=(Y_1,\ldots, Y_r)'
$$
We now use that $B$ is idempotent (1.), which yields
$$
B^2=B \implies P\Delta P'P\Delta P' = P\Delta P' \\
\implies P\Delta^2 P' = P\Delta P' \\
\implies \Delta^2 = \Delta \\
\implies \lambda^2_i = \lambda_i \ \forall i\in \{1,\ldots,r\} \\
\implies \lambda_i\in\{0, 1\}  \ \forall i\in \{1,\ldots,r\}
$$
So we have shown that
$$
X'GX = Z'BZ = Y'\Delta Y = \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda_i Y^2_i = \sum_{{i=1} \\ {\lambda_i\ne 0}}^r Y^2_i 
$$
This completes the proof since $Y_i$ are iid. standard normal distributed rv's.
For much more general results cf. [2], chapter 9. In particular Theorem 9.2.1 is a generalization of what has been proven here.
References:
[1] Horn, R. A. & Johnson, C. R., Matrix Analysis, 2nd edition, Cambridge University Press (2013)
[2] Rao, C. R. & Mitra, S. K., Generalized Inverse of Matrices and its Applications, J. Wiley & Sons Inc. (1971)

dear @Dr_Be, I do not see chapter 9 in [2]...

@ABK Please take care, there is an article of the same authors from the same year with a similar title ("..of a matrix"). But this is from a symposium at the University of Berkeley. There it is chapter 7 and Theorem 7.3, but its shorter. The book [2] has eleven chapters. ISBN 10/13 are 0471708216/9780471708216.

The answer is yes. To see why, assume firstly that the covariance is diagonal: $\Sigma=Diag(\sigma_1^2,\dots, \sigma_r^2,0,\dots,0)$. The generalized inverse is $G=Diag(\sigma_1^{-2},\dots, \sigma_r^{-2},0,\dots,0)$. And $X$ is equal in distribution to $(\sigma_1Y_1,\dots, \sigma_rY_r,0,\dots,0)$ where $Y_i$ are iid unit normal variables.
Then $X^TGX=\sum_{i=1}^r(\sigma_iY_i)^2\sigma_i^{-2}=\sum_{i=r}^rY_i^2$ which is indeed $\chi$^2 with $r$ degrees of freedom.
In the general case, we can diagonalize the covariance matrix $\Sigma=UDU^T$ where $D$ is of the form above and $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. Moreover, $G=UD_+U^T$ where $D_+$ is the pseudoinverse of $D$. Then
$$X^TGX=X^TUD_+U^TX=(U^TX)^TD_+(U^TX)$$
On the other hand, $U^TX$ is multivariate normal (since it is a linear transformation of a multivariate normal) with covariance matrix $$\mathbb{E}U^TX(U^TX)^T=\mathbb{E}U^TXX^TU=U^T(\mathbb{E}XX^T)U=U^T\Sigma U=D$$
So by the above analysis in the diagonal case, we know that (a) $(U^TX)^TD_+(U^TX)$ has the claimed $\chi^2$ distribution and (b) $(U^TX)^TD_+(U^TX)=X^TGX$.

why $G=UD_+U^T$ where $D_+$ is the pseudoinverse of $D$?

what is matrix $E$?

@ABK, the expression $G=UD_+U^T$ is essentially the definition of the pseudoinverse (replace each non-zero eigenvalue with its inverse), and $E$ is not a matrix, it is the expectation operator (clarified in post)
